Laravel 11 Route URL does not work, it returns 127.0.0.1 refused to connect ERROR
I’m trying to make a simple button that linking to a form page on my Laravel 11 project using Project Idx (cloud code editor by Google). The button contains a Route code:
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{ route('iku.create') }}" role="button">Tambah IKU</a>

when I hover the button, I see the url “127.0.0.1:9002/iku/create”. “iku” is the folder’s name and “create” is the php file’s name where the form page exists.
enter image description here
When I click the button, it doesn’t redirect to the correct page. Instead, it shows an error 127.0.0.1 refused to connect. . Also the address bar shows a message (external page) .
I’ve tried to make the button with a simple href method
<a href="iku/create">Tambah IKU</a>

and this code runs properly. Of course, this method is not the proper one I want to use.
However, this code shows different url when it is hovered. It shows,
https://9000-idx-pkrbaru-1724910462366.cluster-e3wv6awer5h7kvayyfoein2u4a.cloudworkstations.dev/iku/create 

Here is the Route code:
Route::resource('/iku', \App\Http\Controllers\ikucontroller::class);

Also, I've checked php artisan route:list
  GET|HEAD        / ......................................................................... 
  GET|HEAD        coba ...................................................................... 
  GET|HEAD        iku ....................................... iku.index › ikucontroller@index
  POST            iku ....................................... iku.store › ikucontroller@store
  GET|HEAD        iku/create .............................. iku.create › ikucontroller@create
  GET|HEAD        iku/{iku} ................................... iku.show › ikucontroller@show
  PUT|PATCH       iku/{iku} ............................... iku.update › ikucontroller@update
  DELETE          iku/{iku} ............................. iku.destroy › ikucontroller@destroy
  GET|HEAD        iku/{iku}/edit .............................. iku.edit › ikucontroller@edit
  GET|HEAD        registrasi .......... registrasi.form › authcontroller@tampilformregistrasi
  POST            registrasi/submit ........... registrasi.submit › authcontroller@klikdaftar
  GET|HEAD        up ........................................................................ 

and here is the code in ikucontroller.php
class ikucontroller extends Controller
{
    
    public function create() : View {
        return view('iku.create');
    }
}

Is there something wrong with the Route or the localhost setting? or it is just a bug in Project Idx?
